# Как выполнить json запрос из Java?

Tags: java, json, яндекс-директ

[Тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/direct/doc/start/format-docpage/) инструкция от яндекса как выполнить запрос, который возвращает список компаний.

Я написал код, но он не возвращает список компаний
Что я делаю не так?

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://api-sandbox.direct.yandex.com/json/v5/campaigns");
        request.addHeader("method", "post");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer AQAAAAArF4HVAAWVTS-0xmCgpENLj6IZXHfvJ_o");
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("{\"method\":\"get\",\"params\":{\"SelectionCriteria\":{},\"FieldNames\":[\"Id\",\"Name\"]}}");
        request.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

Когда делаю запрос в консоли curl, все работает, как надо.

Запрос:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer AQAAAAArF4HVAAWVTS-0xmCgpENLj6IZXHfvJ_o" -d "{\"method\":\"get\",\"params\":{\"SelectionCriteria\":{},\"FieldNames\":[\"Id\",\"Name\"]}}" https://api-sandbox.direct.yandex.com/json/v5/campaigns
```

Ответ:

```
{"result":
    {"Campaigns":
        [
            {"Name":"Test API Sandbox campaign 1","Id":318390}, 
            {"Id":318391,"Name":"Test API Sandbox campaign 2"}, 
            {"Id":318392,"Name":"Test API Sandbox campaign 3"}
        ]
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы все сделали верно, за исключением того что response это только объект, содержащий ссылку на поток, из которого нужно прочитать ответ:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

Вот код целиком:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://api-sandbox.direct.yandex.com/json/v5/campaigns");
    request.addHeader("method", "post");
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en");
    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer AQAAAAArF4HVAAWVTS-0xmCgpENLj6IZXHfvJ_o");
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("{\"method\":\"get\",\"params\":{\"SelectionCriteria\":{},\"FieldNames\":[\"Id\",\"Name\"]}}");
    request.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
}
```

Вот то, что он вывел в консоль:

`result = {"result":{"Campaigns":[{"Id":318390,"Name":"Test API Sandbox campaign 1"},{"Name":"Test API Sandbox campaign 2","Id":318391},{"Name":"Test API Sandbox campaign 3","Id":318392}]}}`

Comment: Спасибо большое! 
Подскажите пож-та еще как в подобных ситуациях понять что это поток?
И можно как нибудь увидеть все данные ответа, заголовки, статусы и т.п.?

Comment: @JavaDev я обычно ищу документацию...